# What is this icon at the top of the screen?

Tags: sniper-elite-3

On a couple of occasions I've noticed this icon at the top of the screen when playing Sniper Elite III:

[image]

What does this mean? It doesn't seem to be explained in the game's manual.

**Update**: [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHyMF.png) (from [@Despato](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/74022/despato)'s answer) shows the word "GHOST" underneath the icon. I don't recall seeing it myself, but perhaps it simply disappears after some time. A quick [online search for "sniper elite 3 ghost"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sniper%20elite%203%20ghost) turns up a [couple](http://steamcommunity.com/app/238090/discussions/0/540744936723095144) [results](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/707653-sniper-elite-iii/69588303), but the information is speculative at best, both in terms of what triggers the icon and what its effect is. Would be nice to have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/sniper-elite-iii/239735-sniper-elite-3-trophy-guide-roadmap-2.html) forum, It seems that the icon you mentioned appears whenever you evade the notice of an enemy who had noticed you and was engaging you.
The reason this icon appears is because if you do this 'engage and evade' maneuver 100 times, it results in an achievement called 'Oscar Mike'.

Edit: [This](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/707653-sniper-elite-iii/69588303) forum post also has another possibility:

> I think it has to do with killing and then re-locating before you're spotted. If you successfully re-locate without being spotted, you get "ghost" status.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm pretty sure I've successfully relocated plenty of times without that icon showing up, so I think there's more to it than that.

Comment: A likely explanation is that the icon only appears in increments of 10, so as to indicate progression to the achievement.

Comment: No, the message that shows achievement progress is different, it actually shows the name of the achievement as well as how far you've progressed (e.g. "50/100").

Comment: Also the HUD glows for a period of time. Is the player harder to detect during that time?

Answer (score -1):

When you relocate but some of soldiers know you, you'll be a ghost.
If you be a ghost, killing soldiers give you more score.

Comment: Is there any empirical evidence for this?

Comment: I experienced it myself